# Is a fistula through a torso possible?

Tags: physiology, stage-magic

I recently read about the "Huamn Pincushion" [Mirin Dajo](http://ramenandpickles.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/human-pincushion-mirin-dajo/) who used to apparently pierce his own torso on stage.

All the reports seem to agree, that this was not fake. X-Ray images and video footage seem to support that.

One of the explanations is that he slowly created [fistulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fistula) through his body, which enabled him to push a sword through without loss of blood.

My question is: is it possible or feasible to create a fistula through your torso?

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexis_St._Martin